# Is there a way to set a wrap length on a Tkinter Text Widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

**Question**

I am trying to make a text editor in Tkinter. If a large single-line file is opened, it lags massively and stops responding. Is there a way to set a wrap length for a text widget? I have scroll bars and I don't want to have the characters wrap at the end of the text box. I want it to wrap after a certain number of characters.

Is this possible?
If so, how can I do it?

I am using Python 3.9.6 on 64-bit Windows 10.

**What I have tried**

I have tried using wraplength= in the function, but that doesn't work. I have also searched for this question and found nothing.

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Notpad [new file]')
root.geometry('1225x720')
      
txt = Text(root,width=150,height=40,wrap=NONE)
txt.place(x=0,y=0)
#Buttons here
        
scr = Scrollbar(root)
scr.pack(side='right',fill='y',expand=False)
txt.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
scr.config(command=txt.yview)
scr1 = Scrollbar(root,orient='horizontal')
scr1.pack(side='bottom',fill='x',expand=False)
txt.config(xscrollcommand=scr1.set)
scr1.config(command=txt.xview)
     
        
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you share more code? (if it's too much, you might need to shorten it into a minimal reproducible example)

Comment: I've added some code now. @Someone_who_likes_SE
I'm sorry for the indents

Comment: I'm just wondering how many letters are on that single line?

Comment: I found some file with 82 KB on one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `wraplength` option in tkinter `Text` widget.  However you can *simulate* the effect using `rmargin` option of `tag_configure()`.

Below is an example with a custom text widget using `rmargin` option:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font

class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        self.wraplength = kw.pop('wraplength', 80)
        # create an instance variable of type font.Font
        # it is required because Font.measure() is used later
        self.font = font.Font(master, font=kw.pop('font', ('Consolas',12)))
        super().__init__(master, font=self.font, **kw)
        self.update_rmargin() # keep monitor and update "rmargin"

    def update_rmargin(self):
        # determine width of a character of current font
        char_w = self.font.measure('W')
        # calculate the "rmargin" in pixel
        rmargin = self.winfo_width() - char_w * self.wraplength
        # set up a tag with the "rmargin" option set to above value
        self.tag_config('rmargin', rmargin=rmargin, rmargincolor='#eeeeee')
        # apply the tag to all the content
        self.tag_add('rmargin', '1.0', 'end')
        # keep updating the "rmargin"
        self.after(10, self.update_rmargin)

root = tk.Tk()

textbox = MyText(root, width=100, font=('Consolas',12), wrap='word', wraplength=90)
textbox.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

# load current file
with open(__file__) as f:
    textbox.insert('end', f.read())

root.mainloop()
```

Note that I have used `after()` so that even there are changes on the content, the `rmargin` option is applied to updated content.

Note also that it may not be an efficient way, but it shows a possible way.